# Rails Sunspot Solr reindex slow only on prod, but not on staging and local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, reindex

I have been reindex my solr manually since the app is pretty limited and it sometimes requires me to go and manually fix something in the MySQL database. Then i reindex the solr to match the changes. On local and staging the reindex runs just fine. On production though it usually takes 20 minutes (which is fine), but suddenly after we applied the capistrano deployment it will take 20 hours for 60k results.I think it's a server issue since it works fine on other environments - do you have any other ideas since i don't have much control over the server? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the production and capistrano deployment done to different servers? Could it be a plain server performance issue? (disk/memory/etc.?) Use a profiler to see where time is being spent on the different deployments and compare to find where the issue can be - my guess is it'll be hard to give a decent answer with the information provided.